# error: 'kInAppPurchaseProUpgradeProductId' undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: iphone

I am new to inapp  purchase and I am trying to implement in app purchase in my app I have created a provision profile also I had added the app to itunes but know when I am trying to deploy on my device it shows following error.

```
error: 'kInAppPurchaseManagerProductsFetchedNotification' undeclared (first use in this function)

error: 'kInAppPurchaseManagerProductsFetchedNotification' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Comment: I am also experiencing same for while :) thanks, you asked and my day made up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you copy and paste code without understanding it you have to copy everything.

you forgot this line:

```
#define kInAppPurchaseManagerProductsFetchedNotification @"kInAppPurchaseManagerProductsFetchedNotification"
```